# No code solution to restrict views for Infopath 2013?

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

I'm using InfoPath 2013 with two views, one for the user entry and one for the admin staff.  I need to restrict the view for the admin staff to a few users.  How does one go about doing this in InfoPath 2013 without code?

First group: Site Owners can see the ADMIN view

Second group: Site Members cannot see the ADMIN view

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways I can think of to achieve this.

1. Create Button that looks for currentUser in button rule.
2. Create a text box where a user can enter a secret password.

1st

1. create text field called "currentUser" and set the default value to the function userName(). - this will get the current user logged in.
2. create text field called "adminUsers" and enter all the ids of the admin users. (this will depend on your organization) my case it would be my badgeID. You can use userName() to get your ID.
3. create a button with rules
4. in the button rules create  a new action
5. in the Conditions area create a condition that states "adminUsers(the field) contains currentUser(the field)) you will have to click "use a formula, then click insert Field or Group.
6. Now under Run these actions: switch views to your admin view.

2nd

1. Create text field called password
2. Create button with rules
3. Set condition on button where password is equal to "yourPassword"

in this scenario, your admin users will be required to enter it each time verses the app knowing who you they are.